# How to create a solution template in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to create a Solution Template in VS2010?
I need to create a solution with several projects already created....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find a blog post with an example at http://bloggemdano.blogspot.com/2010/05/creating-f-solution-template-for-visual.html.

Comment: Direct link to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I guess this is the direct link to the blog post: http://bloggemdano.blogspot.com/2010/05/creating-f-solution-template-for-visual.html

Comment: F# - eww! hairball! ick!

Answer (score 5):

Solution templates do not exist.  A VSTemplate type can be Project or Item, reference [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31cdwx28.aspx).  This is also visible from File + Export Template.

Maybe you could write a macro to copy/create the required files.

Comment: If that is true (and I am not disputing what you're saying) then how does someone create a template like some of the starter kits?  I found this online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308 (how to create multi-project templates.  Maybe that is what I'm looking for....

Comment: Yes, looks to me that this ought to be a good start for 2010 projects.  Bummer on the crummy docs.  The start kits were project templates afaik.

Comment: although Blank Solution is an option in VS2012

Comment: There is a link "How To: Create Multi-Project Templates" which sounds like a Solution template to me.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185308(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

That's not a VS template, but you can use tempify to create folder templates - http://opensource.endjin.com/templify/

"*Templify has two modes – Create and Deploy. In Create mode you can take a pre-existing solution and turn it into a deployable template...*"