# Solution/MultiProject Template in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, reference, solution, multi-project

Looking to make a Solution/Multiproject Template.

While I'm aware a solution template does not exist, I've been researching/trying with some of success. (Link from here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717110/how-to-create-a-solution-template-in-vs2010) have been a big help.

The only issue I'm facing is that, when creating a project from my template, the solution contains brand-new copies of all of the projects involved. What I require is that only ONE project is made as a fresh copy, and that the other projects in the template should reference already-existing projects.

I've made single project templates that hold the DLL references to other projects (which is fine, but it's not what I need.) I need a multi-project template where all but one project involved reference already existing projects...

How would I go about this?

edit:
I'm also finding that any dbml designer.cs that's added to a project are not included in the newly generated solution/projects. They are copied across, but I then have to manually include them in the project. Why is this, and how do I get araound it?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Feature Builder Power Tool? 
 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67b720f4-9a50-41cb-86a2-82e33b7c5fc4/

It should give you all the freedom to create whatever logic you want during solution setup...

Comment: Seems to have some negative feedback in regards to it's integration with Visual Studio, hampering functionality, etc...

Any other recommendations?

Comment: I just know that it exists... :-) I haven't had a chance yet to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't find a workaround for this issue.

What I have managed to do though is make a decent enough template that should be run once, with all references (being relative) pointing to an outside lib folder.

This means I can use the template on a new machine, copy some dlls to a new lib folder, and then work away from there. Not an ideal solution, but it works...